How to grab an image based on the first identifier in a list, and rename the image to the second identifier
I have several thousand students, all with two unique identifiers (one is a 4 digit number and one is an 8 digit number). I also have a standard windows folder of JPG images, where every image is the photo of a student, named with the 4 digit identifier.
I am able to generate a simple CSV list containing both the 4 digit identifier and its corresponding 8 digit identifier.
I need to be able to run some process that compares every file in the list to the 4 digit identifier and renames the file to the 8 digit identifier.
Is anyone able to guide me please.
Cheers
Phil
I am able to separate out the identifiers and create a list. I have tried some basic batch processing and some excel scripts but have reached beyond the boundaries of my ability.

Please post some sample data which would show the contents of your CSV. I'm assuming it's just a series of rows in the format of <4_digit_id>,<8_digit_id>, but I think it would be better for us to see the actual content of your CSV. Regarding the renaming itself - what is your preferred way of doing this? Batch, Powershell, something else?
